# User condition online with last login with time()

Tags: php, time, authentication

I searched a bit in the various posts, but I couldn't find a solution for me. However, I would simply like to show the text "Online" and "Offline" to a user based on his last login with time () of less than 5 minutes.

What would be the exact condition?
Thanks a lot to those who will help me.

```
if($last_login < .....) {
   echo "online"; 
   } else { 
   echo "Offline" 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the time 5 minutes ago, and check if the last login was after that:

```
if ($last_login >= time() - 5 * 60) {
    echo "online"; 
} else { 
   echo "Offline" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(time()-$last_login)/60` will calculate the difference between current time and last  login in minutes.
So the code will be:

```
if(((time()-$last_login)/60) < 5)
{
   echo "online"; 
} 
else 
{ 
   echo "Offline" ;
}
```